# the components does not displayed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router, laravel-5.8

I intalled vue.js and vuetify in my project laravel. i configurate the vue-router to build a single page application. besides loading http://localhost:8000/accueil the components doesn't displayed 
and i get this error in the console "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error"

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');



import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);



let routes = [{
    path: '/accueil',
    component: require('./components/Accueil.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    component: require('./components/Home.vue')
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router // <-- register router with Vue


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user() }}">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <title>SGAT Dashboard</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/blue/pace-theme-corner-indicator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>

    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- `<router-link>` will be rendered as an `<a>` tag by default -->
    <router-link to="/accueil">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/Home">Go to Bar</router-link>


    <router-view></router-view>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="344"
  >
    <v-card-text>
      <div>Word of the Day</div>
      <p class="display-1 text--primary">
        be•nev•o•lent
      </p>
      <p>adjective</p>
      <div class="text--primary">
        well meaning and kindly.<br>
        "a benevolent smile"
      </div>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        text
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
      >
        Learn More
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
             <script>
    export default {
  
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `require` here:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

You should be using `import`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import './bootstrap';

window.Vue = Vue;
```

Comment: i replaced it now but the components does not display

Comment: i get 2 errors :                                                            * app.js:6056 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>                                                                             *  Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Comment: when i access manually to the URL http://localhost:8000/accueil i get the page blade without components and the error Fanifest: Line:1, column: 1, Syntax error.                                                       Moreover, when i click in the link  <router-link to="/home">Go to Bar</router-link>  the URL was http://localhost:8000/accueil#/home not http://localhost:8000/home and i get the error :[Vue warn] Failed to mount component template or order function not defined

Comment: I see some places where you are still using `require`. You should instead move them to the top of the file as `imports`. On another note, there seems to be a lot wrong with your code base. I would suggested starting from scratch with a clean and simple Vue application that works. And then add features step by step. Because right now I think there is more than 1 thing wrong.

Comment: have you any document or tutorial that could help me ? i didin't like to do a new project because i'll lose time repeating working of  3 months . i want an easy way to make my app as SPA

Comment: Try looking at how this is setup: https://codesandbox.io/s/qx3orn736q